# How to design ASP.NET Core - SQL application where user should be able to create forms of different input items and store values in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I've started working on a web application project, where a feature is: the admin user can create/update few custom forms choosing different input types from the database and the end users can update the form data in a repetitive fashion/sometimes daily and the data stores in the database for further use cases. To elaborate, the admin user can choose any of "**checkbox**", "**textbox**", "**textarea**", "**datetime**", "**temperature**" etc. input types and create a form. The end user then can read the form and input the values that is to be saved in the database for reporting to admin.

I need to use ASP.NET Core MVC, SQL, EF, code first migration at the back-end of the project.

I am thinking maybe (as an example) a `Form model with Id and Name properties`, `TextBox model with Id, Name, FormId`, `DateTime model with Id, Name, FormId` etc. for creating the forms and then when user inputs values that can be updated using other models/tables in the database like `TextBoxRecord model with Id, TextBoxId, Value, UserId, DateEntered etc.` But then it will be too many tables to update and read every time when entering values and displaying reports to the admin.

I appreciate any help with a good design idea of the data model or how to attain this kind of logic. Also feel free ask, if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: Whoever down-voted my question, why not post a comment and let me know what was wrong in this question? I did try google for days before asking question here and I had no idea that I could use serialization as @vasily.sib suggested. So, what is the expectation from a new developer's question type? May be I can get better from the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago, I was working on some simular project. We don't store each of our form field in DB, because we don't want to update DB each time we need to add some *new-kind-of-form-field*. We believe it's up to HTML+JS to decide what kind of input to use with particular object property.

We create a serializer, that serialize form structure in **xml** and store it in DB. In this xml we keep a **TableName** (EF `DataSet<>` name) and **ColumnName** (name of model property) for each FormField.

When we need to show a form to user, we deserialize it from DB, pack in **ViewModel** (because we don't want to show to user real names of our DB tables) and send it to **JavaScript** code as JSON. JS then constructs the form element and show it to user. When user submits the data, we again deserialize corresponding form from DB and update actual models in db with data from user input.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This gives me a good starting point. Can I spend this weekend to read about XML serialization and come back to you, if I need further help?

Comment: Xml serialization is simple, you can start with [reading about XmlSerializer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2). Sure, you can add a comment if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

To all the, eurhm, people, who find this an interesting question and "would like to know the answer too", there's an interesting article to read at

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

That story started with (at least as good as) *exactly* the same kind of user requirement as the OP's here.

(And to those who want to downvote this because "not an answer" : it is MORE of an answer because it shows in intimate detail *WHY* you *NEVER* want to even start going down that alley.)